# Instant Run disabled for multidexed application

Tags: android, android-studio

Using Android Studio 2.0 with gradle 2.0.0, I see the following error:

> Instant Run is disabled:
>            Instant Run does not support deploying build variants with multidex enabled, to a target with API level 20 or below.
>            To use Instant Run with a multidex enabled build variant, deploy to a target with API level 21 or higher.
>            (Don't show again)

Why am I not able to use Instant Run?

Comment: as the error message tells you, you can only use Instant Run with multidexed applications when deploying to a target device with SDK Level >= 21

Comment: But I want to know Why ?

Comment: Are you testing on a device with Android 4.4 or lower?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you can only use Instant Run with multidexed applications when deploying to a target device with SDK Level >= 21.

You can read more about the [limitations of instant run](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#ir-limitations) on the Android Developers Page. Instant run can only be used when

- deploying to only one target device at a time
- multidex is disabled or your target device's SDK level is >= 21

Also note that third-party plugins (e.g. ProGuard) are temporarily disabled when using instant run.

Comment: I have been trying Instant Run on and off for about 6 months.  My project is based on the iosched v2015 and Instant Run doesn't help with a project of this size.   It either gives a blank screen for 60 seconds on an uninstall / install cycle (while dexing), or now (with 2.2Beta) hit the 65K method limit after I tried adding in Expresso test recording.   My development experience is better (still) if I turn off Instant Run (File / Settings / Build, etc / Instant Run / uncheck everything).